# Jquery - Scroll event on a non scrollable div

Tags: jquery, scroll

**example:** http://jsbin.com/ofifiy/2/edit#preview

i try to scroll a div (red one) with a non scrollable div (green one).
My problem is, when i scroll on the green div, the jquery `scroll()` does not fire.

**HTML**

```
<div id="targetWithNoScroll" style="border:1px solid #0f0;  width:100px; height:100px;">
    scroll here = scroll the red div<br />   
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#targetWithNoScroll').scroll(function() {
  $('body').append('No scroll <br />');
});
```

Comment: Why would you expect a scroll event to fire on a div which has no ability to scroll? This seems correct behaviour to me.

Comment: Please explain the logic here. You apply a listener to something that does not fire (scrolling in a non-scrollable div), so you can output "nothing happened" in the callback? That does not make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind the mousewheel event to that div.
Unfortunately there is no native jQuery mousewheel event, so you have to pick a plugin or write it yourself. But I would recommend taking one of these as it saves you a lot of time:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

1) Load jQuery and the Mouse Wheel plugin
Mouse Wheel plugin is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel).

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

2) Attach mousewheel event to body
The "30" represents speed. preventDefault ensures the page won't scroll down.

```js
$(function() {
   $("#element").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollTop -= (delta * 30);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: all 3 links are dead

Comment: I inserted the content, so it won't get lost. Unfortunately, though, I cannot insert the whole framework, so I have to link it

Comment: That's completely fair, just stumbled upon this and all 3 links were dead. css-tricks seem to be reliable to link to over time.