# Javascript doesn't work in firefox and IE/edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a piece of code, that's changing my div background on mousescroll and it's working fine in Chrome and Opera, but it doesn't in Firefox and IE/Edge.

I have two divs, the inner one has a background image that is changing on scroll down, the outer one is simply bigger so there is space to scroll. 
In Firefox and IE/Edge, the scroll or doesn't work either skips an image, sometimes even doesn't purceed to scrolling the rest of the content on the website.

http://jsfiddle.net/s6qrfo9n/1/ 
Any ideas why?

Here it is (and I know it's poorly written, but I'm new to javascript and it does the job):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numberofscroll = 0;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $("#home").scroll(function(){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--;
        console.log(numberofscroll);
        console.log(lastScrollTop);
        console.log(st);
        if (numberofscroll<2){
            change_background2(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<3){
            change_background3(numberofscroll);
        }
        else if (numberofscroll<4){
            change_background4(numberofscroll);
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    });

    function change_background2(numberofscroll){
    var i; 
    for (i = 2; i <= 2; i++) {
        $("#home").css("background-image","url('images/movie_" + i + ".jpg')");
    }
}

      function change_background3(numberofscroll){
    var i; 
    for (i = 3; i <= 3; i++) {
        $("#home").css("background-image","url('images/movie_" + i + ".jpg')");
    }
}

    function change_background4(numberofscroll){
    var i; 
    for (i = 4; i <= 4; i++) {
        $("#home").css("background-image","url('images/movie_" + i + ".jpg')");
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Please paste a snippet for better reference

Comment: @ShanKhaliq I'm trying to make it work right now, but the images do not change for some reason ... http://jsfiddle.net/denea/s6qrfo9n/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s6qrfo9n/1/ try this one

Comment: @ShanKhaliq Thanks a lot, updated with a better explanation of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the smooth scrolling feature of firefox and ie (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996067/turn-off-firefoxs-smooth-scrolling)).  This causes the jQuery `scroll` event to fire multiple times every time you scroll, thus the 'missing' images--they are being put in, but then they're replaced so fast you can't see them.

Unfortunately, since you can't disable the smooth scrolling feature on people's browsers, there isn't really a perfect solution to this.  The best solution is to debounce your `scroll` event handler.  There are many ways to implement a debounce (google it for some ideas).  A simple one would be just toggling a boolean after a timeout and checking it every time you run the function:

```
var dontHandle = false;
$("#home").scroll(function () {
    if (dontHandle) return; // Debounce this function.
    dontHandle = true;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        dontHandle = false;
    }, 400); // Debounce!--don't let this function run again for 400 milliseconds.
});
```

Here's your updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6qrfo9n/3/).  You may need to play with the debounce time.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your code is working as intended but I have a couple thoughts about the `scroll` event.

The `scroll` event will only be fired if scrolling actually takes place. Nothing will happen if your div doesn't scroll. You could get around that by using another library, check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397534/jquery-scroll-event-on-a-non-scrollable-div#answer-8397791) for some suggested libraries. Also, keep in mind that the `scroll` event is extremely sensitive, so the "skipping" of images may simply be a result of scrolling too fast.

I cleaned up your code to make better use of the `change_background` function.

```
var numberofscroll = 0;
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#home").scroll(function(e) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        console.log(numberofscroll, lastScrollTop, st);

        (st > lastScrollTop) ? numberofscroll++ : numberofscroll--;

        //make sure numberofscroll stays in range
        if(numberofscroll <= 0) {
            numberofscroll = 1;
        } else if(numberofscroll > 4) {
            numberofscroll = 4;
        }

        change_background(numberofscroll);

        lastScrollTop = st;
    });

    function change_background(numberofscroll) {

        $("#home").css("background-image","url('http://coverjunction.s3.amazonaws.com/manual/low/colorful" + numberofscroll + ".jpg')");
    }
});
```

Your `change_background` functions have been rolled into one function and `numberofscroll` will stay within a certain range to ensure the image you want actually exists.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for cleaning, but it didn't help with Firefox/IE/Edge. I don't scroll too fast, I single scroll it. I thought it could be something in the css, but it skips images ...